# What is this Disney comic with hooded figures wearing golden masks?

Tags: story-identification, comics, disney

It was a Disney comics. I read it (in French) about 20-25 years ago.

I'm not even sure if it was featuring Donald Duck or Mickey Mouse (I think Donald and his nephews), but it was about golden masks (they found one at some place), and strange figures with a full body dark blue / black hood wearing these masks, and just standing in a circle.

And when the characters peeked under the masks, it showed stars, like a universe was there instead of a head.

Any idea what this story was?

Comment: I have vaque memory of reading this one too. I believe it might have been in an issue of the weekly "Káčer Donald" (Slovak version of Donald Duck) magazine back in the 90's or more likely very early 2000's. I tried searching in my language, but unfortunately found nothing as there is no complete online archive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't have compelling evidence, but there is a chance the comic you are looking for is [*"Zio Paperone e le maschere d'oro"*](https://inducks.org/story.php?c=I+TL+1906-A) ("Uncle Scrooge and the golden masks").

[image: Title page of the sory "Zio Paperone e le maschere d'oro"]

It's a 1992 story written by Rodolfo Cimino and drawn by Alessandro Gottardo, originally published in the Italian Mickey Mouse weekly comic and later translated in other languages. According to I.N.D.U.C.K.S., there is a French translation dated 1994, which *almost* fits *"20-25 years ago"*. There is no mention of a Slovak version though, so either user byMaelstromer is remembering a different comic, or this is not the right one.

Besides Scrooge, if features Donald and his nephews (together with Scrooge's butler), and the title panel shows some black-robed figures with golden masks. I couldn't find any other image, so I cannot confirm the other details you remember.

Comment: A Google search for "zio paperone e le maschere d'oro" returns an [Amazon item](https://www.amazon.it/belle-storie-Maschera-Storie-fumetti-ebook/dp/B01CK7OU7Y), a collection of stories including this one; unfortunately the free sample does not include pages from this story. The comic is free to read for users with a Kindle Unlimited subscription.

Comment: *maschere* is "shockingly similar" to masquerade.  And to mascara (though the words aren't related).

Comment: This is it, you're amazing!